# CameraX exposure time issue

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-camera2, android-camerax

I am using CameraX API with Camera2Interop to set CaptureRequests.

I have problem when setting exposure time via CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME.
While setting exposure time works, its way too dark in comparison with devices stock application.
Here is how i do calculations for exposure.

1. I get `cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_EXPOSURE_TIME_RANGE);`
2. I pass upperValue of gotten `Range<Integer>` to a Method.
3. Method that gets upper value has range of my own supported `Rational` numbers. Method does simple multiplication e.g. (imagine this is sensor upper value)100_000_000 * 1/6.
4. Recalculated value is finally sent to `CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME`.
5. Result is visually obviously darker image then for exact same values from stock device camera application. e.g. 100_000_000 * 1/1 when i set it to max. Details in gallery show 1/10s exposure for my apps image and 1s for stock app.

To make this even more confusing is that in case of this testing device, device stock app has up to 10s max exposure time while `cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_EXPOSURE_TIME_RANGE);` for the same device show 1s as maximum.